# Problem with figure captions on two different slides

Tags: beamer, floats, columns

I am having problems with figure captions. Currently, my captions are appearing at the bottom of both two slides. However, I want the captions to appear below the figure on separate slides. Please help, below is my code.

```
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Titan}
        \begin{columns}

        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering

        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics<1>[height=4cm]{PIA14445.jpg}
            \caption<1>{(Courtesy NASA/JPL-Caltech.)}

            \includegraphics<2>[height=4cm]{outgassing.pdf}
            \caption<2>{(Tobie et al., 2006)}

        \end{figure}

        \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Features/Missions}
            \begin{itemize}
            \item Largest Moon of Saturn
            \item Cassini-Huygens mission
            \item Presence of Subsurface Ocean + Crust Made of Ice I
            \item Atmosphere (Nitrogen/Methane)
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Methane needs to be replenished from the interior
            \end{enumerate}
            \end{itemize}

        \end{block}

        \end{columns}

    \end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please provide us with a complete code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and try to avoid including figures that others here do not have, i.e. use something like `example-image-a` instead. Have you tried using two figures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}[t]
        \frametitle{Titan}
        \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering

        \only<1>{\begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}
            \caption{(Courtesy NASA/JPL-Caltech.)}
        \end{figure}}%
        \only<2>{\begin{figure} 
            \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}
            \caption{(Tobie et al., 2006)}
        \end{figure}}
        \end{column}%
        \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Features/Missions}
            \begin{itemize}
            \item Largest Moon of Saturn
            \item Cassini-Huygens mission
            \item Presence of Subsurface Ocean + Crust Made of Ice I
            \item Atmosphere (Nitrogen/Methane)
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Methane needs to be replenished from the interior
            \end{enumerate}
            \end{itemize}

        \end{block}
        \end{column}%
        \end{columns}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]